# Is there a way I can encrypt a text file containing a password, store it on a Windows VM, and use it in a Powershell script to create a PSCredential?

Tags: powershell, encryption

Title says it all, really. I'd like to be able to create a text file that only contains a password, encrypt the file, store it on a server, and then create a Powershell script that can look at the file and create a PSCredential object using the password in the file?

Comment: `$cred | Export-CliXml` >> The XML will only be usable by the user who exported the file and only in the host where the file was exported.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a known unencrypted value, you would create a `SecureString`, convert that to an encrypted string, and write it to a file. Then reverse the process to decrypt it:

```
# 1. Start with plain text (this is an example I don't expect you to store these values here!)
$user = "myUser"
$plainSecret = "mySecret"
# 2. Convert to SecureString
$secureSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $plainSecret -AsPlainText -Force
# 3. Convert to encrypted string (using a key I made up - you'll want to do better, but this illustrates the point - I do not expect you to store these values here!)
$encryptedKey = @(102, 200, 12, 33, 6, 253, 21, 88, 144, 0, 0, 233, 202, 112, 41, 67) 
$encryptedSecret = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secureSecret -Key $encryptedKey
# 4. Write that to a file
$encryptedSecret | Set-Content securesecret.txt
# 5. Now get the value back (read the file, decrypt into SecureString)
$decryptedSecret = Get-Content securesecret.txt | 
  ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $encryptedKey 
# 6. Create a credential
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $myUser, $decryptedSecret
```

Comment: This is a good approach in case `Export-CliXml` is not an option, the only problem with this is that the credentials are not very secure. Anyone with access to the source code can get the password. The `$encryptedKey` could be exported to a file and set an ACL granting read-access only to the service account running the script, that could secure the code a bit more though anyone with `writedacl` would still be able to sort this out.

Comment: I was really just illustrating the simplest path from A to B using SecureString, it's true that a real implementation would not store these values all in one script. And, in truth, since I'm an Azure guy I'd probably store the secret in Azure Key Vault using the Powershell Az module or az cli. The question doesn't really reference how the OP came into possession of the password that needs to be stored - that would definitely be interesting to know!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not criticizing your answer, I believe is the right answer. My comment was meant for OP, he should be aware of the risks.

Comment: No, I appreciate your perspective on it, and was clarifying also for the OP :)